# ditch the top hat but do scrub up a little

Tags: meaning, slang

What is this supposed to mean?  "ditch the top hat but do scrub up a little."

It is used in an article that talks about a gourmet fare.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means

> make yourself presentable, but don't over do it

To

> scrub up

is to groom oneself, as in "wash up"

> He's usually a slob, but scrubs up nicely.

[[image]][2]
<sub>(source: [memecdn.com](https://img.memecdn.com/before-and-after-with-gillette-fusion_o_1543537.jpg))</sub>

and a

> top hat

is usually worn on very formal occasions

> top hat and tails

[[image]][1]
<sub>(source: [porges.net](http://www.porges.net/Images/astaire/astaire_portrait.jpg))</sub>

So your saying means, "don't be overly formal, but be presentable".
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umxN9.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFkR8.jpg